# Visualforce Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, exception

I get the following Visualforce Error:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Error is in expression '{!checkAccessibility}' in component
>    in page vendorinformation
>   Class.VendorInformation.checkAccessibility: line 45, column 1

I have a class named as `VendorInformation` in which it have a `PageReferences` function called `checkAccessibility();` and there is an error in line num 45:

```
//the error occur n this line
Date ResetTokenDate = date.newinstance(Setting.Reset_Token_Date__c.year(), Setting.Reset_Token_Date__c.month(), Setting.Reset_Token_Date__c.day());

system.debug(ResetTokenDate + 'ResetTokenDate>>.');
system.debug(system.today() + 'system.today()>>.');
system.debug('PortalUser >>>'+PortalUser);
system.debug('ResetTokenDate>>>'+ResetTokenDate);
system.debug('Setting.Entered_Security_Token__c>>>'+Setting.Entered_Security_Token__c);
system.debug('Setting.Security_Token__c>>>'+Setting.Security_Token__c);
if(PortalUser == True && (ResetTokenDate == system.today()) && (Setting.Entered_Security_Token__c == Setting.Security_Token__c)){
            PageReference VendorDetail = new PageReference('/apex/Vendor_Detail');
            return VendorDetail;
}
else
{
    if(PortalUser == True && (ResetTokenDate < system.today())){
        String Token = GenerateSecurityToken(UserInfo.getUserEmail());
        system.debug(token + 'token>>');
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Info,'New Secuirty token has been generated and sent to '+Userinfo.getUserEmail()+'. Copy the Security token from the email and paste it into Security Token field to get access.')); 
    }
    else if(PortalUser == false ){
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'You do not have access to this area.'));
    }

    Setting.Entered_Security_Token__c = ''; 
    return null;
}
```

I call this function from VisualForce:

```
<apex:page controller="VendorInformation" 
           sidebar="false" 
           showHeader="true" 
           id="VendorInformation" 
           action="{!checkAccessibility}">
```

Comment: It would seem that one of Setting or Reset_Token_Date__c is null.

Comment: Do you understand what a NullPointerException means ?

Answer (score 1):

Either Setting or Reset_Token_Date__c is null. Try changing the line as follows:

```
Date ResetTokenDate = setting == null || setting.reset_token_date__c == null? null: setting.reset_token_date__c.date();
```

You'll also need to change your branch conditions accordingly:

```
if(PortalUser && ResetTokenDate != null && ResetTokenDate < Date.Today()) { ...
```

Null pointers cannot be used in some types of expressions, and can never be dereferenced (that is, a dot-notation that accesses any field or method of the object).